# Python's use of global vs specifying the module

Tags: python, variables, module, python-3.x, global

Was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on the use of Python's global vs. referencing the module itself. While in the past I used global when needed, I've found it somewhat clearer to do the second method (and recently have tended to favor this syntax):

```
import sys
mod = sys.modules[__name__]

counter = 0

def incrementGlobal():
    global counter
    counter += 1

def incrementMod():
    mod.counter += 1
```

Obviously both of them work fine, but if anyone has any strong opinions (what is more pythonic, performance etc), I'd love to hear them.

Btw I end up using either of these in situations where the module naturally encapsulates all the methods and attributes of what would be a single class, and rather than reference incrementmodule.IncrementClass.counter i can just use incrementmodule.counter.

Comment: How is the second one clearer?

Comment: i guess it's not THAT much clearer, but i prefer it since it's immediately obvious that a module-level variable is being modified, rather than a local one (keeps you from having to check back to see whether the variable is in the globals declaration at the top)

Comment: If the `global` and the assignment are that far away, you got worse clarity problems than that ;)

Comment: good point :) but I guess it's never sat well with me that when it comes to module-level vars, it's preferable to declare the scope of the vars away from the assignment. If i put all of this in a class, the syntax would obv be IncrementClass.counter, but as i remember reading somewhere that it's pythonic for modules to act on their own (and not have everything be a class), it seems weird that there's not a more natural way to reference the module itself - btw all IMHNoobO :)

Comment: @mlauria: Self-referencing a module is very unusual, so I don't mind that doing it be a little unusual too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with `global` every time. The `global` keyword is an obvious and readily recognisable pattern for modifying something at module level. Giving a module a reference to itself from `sys.modules` seems a needlessly convoluted way of going around it, and is likely to confuse the next programmer who looks at it.

Answer (score 3):

- Performance:  using the `global` style will be *ever so slightly* faster, as it only needs one name lookup instead of two (would only matter in a tight loop of many many thousands).
- Style:  the `mod.xxx` style mirrors the way you would access globals from another module that you had imported:

`

```
import foo
foo.eggs = 'scrambled'
```

The `global` method is more common, but your `mod.xxx` method is also easy to understand and very readable.

Comment: No downvote, but using `global` is far more common than using `mod.xxx`, so I would argue that using `global` is more legible, because this is what almost everybody expects.

Comment: @EOL: Agreed that `global` is the prevailing method, and the more immediately recognizable.